# How to add custom css style to Gutenberg blocks in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to hide the bullets before the items in a Gutenberg list block, so I edit the block as HTML and add the css style as `<ul style="list-style: none;">...</ul>`. But it cannot pass Gutenberg validation. What is the correct way to add custom style to elements in Gutenberg?

Answer (score 1):

In your child theme you can add this css class

```
.style-no-bullet {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Then in the Gutenberg editor, add this class to the list so you want to remove the bullets.

This will not remove the bullets in the Gutenberg editor, but will remove them on the published page.

In the case you would like to use a plu-gin, Twentig is the perfect one for that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/twentig/

Comment: In addition to the answer above, the easiest method of adding additional classes is via selecting the block then in the sidebar *Advanced > Additional CSS class(es)* (https://wordpress.org/support/article/list-block/#block-settings) to avoid Gutenberg block validation issues.

Comment: @ThomasLIBERATO It seems very inconvenient to do so: I need to create a child theme, add the class definition, then add the class.